# Search in mutliple sites using Google Custom Search JSON

Tags: google-custom-search

Trying to figure out how can i search in mutliple sites using Google Custom Search JSON API.
Meaning that search will be **only** from a specific sites list.
i was playing with the api explorer - https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list?apix_params=%7B%22cx%22%3A%22011602274690322925368%3Atkz2zvvpmk0%22%2C%22siteSearch%22%3A%22www.walla.co.il%22%7D
and noticed the site search query key, but it can only accept a single string not a list of sites:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV9Wf.png)

What is the way to search in only in specific site**s**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things you can do.

- If you know the specific sites you want to search, you can add them as [refinements](https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/4542637?hl=en) to your engine. Then query for that refinement by adding 'more:<REFINEMENT_LABEL>' to the query.
- Or, add 'site:' operators to the query itself.  For example [cats site:cnn.com OR site:bbc.com](https://google.com/search?q=cats+site%3Acnn.com+OR+site%3Abbc.com)